# Certain objects in unity 2d cinemachine target group camera offsetted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cinemachine

Im making a star wars game for fun, im using cinemachine to have a target group camera to get the camera between the 2 players and sized appropiatly. The players have hinge joint connecting to lightsabres. When the game starts only the lightsbares are offsetted and nothing else, it isnt like this in scene view. The ground isnt offsetted either. Why? How to fix?

Comment: Welcome to stack over flow. Please publish your question along with the image, code as well as parts of your research.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.